# Getting data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query gets data, but for 116819 rows I need to wait 2:19 minutes. Getting the same data from the table takes 2-3 seconds, but I need some rows from the view (that are matching my data from table) in my query. How can I make it faster? The database that I work on is created properly.

```
select aa.*, b.quantity, b.price, case when b.itemNr is null then 'status' else 'status1' end as Status
    from(
        Select a.*, b.quantity, b.price, b.itemNr
        From table a
        left join view b
        on a.itemNR = b.itemNr and a.itemLine=b.itemLine) aa
    where aa.itemType = 'a type'
    group by ....
    order by ...
```

If I remove `group by` and `order by`, the query takes 2:10 minutes, so I reduce it only by 9 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have resolved my own problem. My problem was that the query was taking too long to display data and this problem came from my join to a **view**! After I found the tables that were creating the view I extracted the one were I found my needed columns and used it in my join. 
Probably the problem in joining **views** is with indexes. I need to read more about indexing a view but I suspect that this was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `SELECT *` with the columns and running it again. [It's generally agreed that `Select* is considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) and can have some fairly major impacts of query performance.